# PHP MYSQL (Modificar Registros) - Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in update.php on line 13

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Espero me puedan ayudar, quiero modificar registros a una tabla de 44 campos, tengo otra tabla relacionada para uno de los campos, y me sale el siguiente error al querer modificar algo: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectos\crud\update.php on line 13

Les dejo mi código, si alguien encuentra el error se lo agradeceré completamente:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
include "header.php";
if(isset($_GET['u'])):
if(isset($_POST['bts'])):
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE computadoras SET id_division=?, centroCosto=?, nombre=?, RPEresponsable=?,
    nombreResponsable=?, latitud=?, longitud=?, notasRevision=?, responsableTI=?, noInventario=?,
    tipo_propiedad=?, resguardoEconomico=?, velocidad=?, nombreEquipo=?, sistemaOperativo=?, direccionIP=?,
    direccionMAC=?, procesador=?, noProcesadores=?, memoria=?, capAlmacenamiento=?, infraCritica=?, funcional=?,
    procesoNegocio=?, tipo_uso=?, actTecnologica=?, no_serie=?, tipo_equipo=?, marca=?, modelo=?, antiguedad=?,
    entidad=?, municipio=?, domicilio=?, zipCode=?, reqMantto, fallas=?, descFalla=?, misionCritica=?, comentarios=?,
    notas=?, migrar=?, no_activoFijo=? WHERE id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss',$id_division,$centroCosto,$nombre,$RPEresponsable,
        $nombreResponsable,$latitud,$longitud,$notasRevision,$responsableTI,$noInventario,$tipo_propiedad,$resguardoEconomico,
        $velocidad,$nombreEquipo,$sistemaOperativo,$direccionIP,$direccionMAC,$procesador,$noProcesadores,$memoria,
        $capAlmacenamiento,$infraCritica,$funcional,$procesoNegocio,$tipo_uso,$actTecnologica,$no_serie,$tipo_equipo,
        $marca,$modelo,$antiguedad,$entidad,$municipio,$domicilio,$zipCode,$reqMantto,$fallas,$descFalla,$misionCritica,
        $comentarios,$notas,$migrar,$no_activoFijo,$id);

    $id_division = $_POST['id_division'];
    $centroCosto = $_POST['centroCosto'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $RPEresponsable = $_POST['RPEresponsable'];
    $nombreResponsable = $_POST['nombreResponsable'];
    $latitud = $_POST['latitud'];
    $longitud = $_POST['longitud'];
    $notasRevision = $_POST['notasRevision'];
    $responsableTI = $_POST['responsableTI'];
    $noInventario = $_POST['noInventario'];
    $tipo_propiedad = $_POST['tipo_propiedad'];
    $resguardoEconomico = $_POST['resguardoEconomico'];
    $velocidad = $_POST['velocidad'];
    $nombreEquipo = $_POST['nombreEquipo'];
    $sistemaOperativo = $_POST['sistemaOperativo'];
    $direccionIP = $_POST['direccionIP'];
    $direccionMAC = $_POST['direccionMAC'];
    $procesador = $_POST['procesador'];
    $noProcesadores = $_POST['noProcesadores'];
    $memoria = $_POST['memoria'];
    $capAlmacenamiento = $_POST['capAlmacenamiento'];
    $infraCritica = $_POST['infraCritica'];
    $funcional = $_POST['funcional'];
    $procesoNegocio = $_POST['procesoNegocio'];
    $tipo_uso = $_POST['tipo_uso'];
    $actTecnologica = $_POST['actTecnologica'];
    $no_serie = $_POST['no_serie'];
    $tipo_equipo = $_POST['tipo_equipo'];
    $marca = $_POST['marca'];
    $modelo = $_POST['modelo'];
    $antiguedad = $_POST['antiguedad'];
    $entidad = $_POST['entidad'];
    $municipio = $_POST['municipio'];
    $domicilio = $_POST['domicilio'];
    $zipCode = $_POST['zipCode'];
    $reqMantto = $_POST['reqMantto'];
    $fallas = $_POST['fallas'];
    $descFalla = $_POST['descFalla'];
    $misionCritica = $_POST['misionCritica'];
    $comentarios = $_POST['comentarios'];
    $notas = $_POST['notas'];
    $migrar = $_POST['migrar'];
    $no_activoFijo = $_POST['no_activoFijo'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    if($stmt->execute()):
        echo "<script>location.href='computadoras.php'</script>";
    else:
        echo "<script>alert('".$stmt->error."')</script>";
    endif;
endif;
$res1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM divisiones");
$row1 = $res1->fetch_assoc();
$res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM computadoras WHERE id=".$_GET['u']);
$row = $res->fetch_assoc();
?>

<p>
</p>
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">

<form role="form" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" id="id" name="id"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="id_division">División</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id_division" id="id_division" value="<?php echo $row1['id_division'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="centroCosto">Centro de Costo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="centroCosto" id="centroCosto" value="<?php echo $row['centroCosto'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="RPEresponsable">RPE del Responsable</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="RPEresponsable" id="RPEresponsable" value="<?php echo $row['RPEresponsable'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombreResponsable">Nombre del Responsable</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreResponsable" id="nombreResponsable" value="<?php echo $row['nombreResponsable'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="latitud">Latitud</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="latitud" id="latitud" value="<?php echo $row['latitud'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="longitud">Longitud</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="longitud" id="longitud" value="<?php echo $row['longitud'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="notasRevision">Notas de RevisióresponsableTIn</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="notasRevision" id="notasRevision" value="<?php echo $row['notasRevision'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="responsableTI">Responsable de TI</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="responsableTI" id="responsableTI" value="<?php echo $row['responsableTI'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="noInventario">Número de Inventario (BIA)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="noInventario" id="noInventario" value="<?php echo $row['noInventario'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tipo_propiedad">Tipo de Propiedad</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tipo_propiedad" id="tipo_propiedad" value="<?php echo $row['tipo_propiedad'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="resguardoEconomico">Resguardo Economico</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="resguardoEconomico" id="resguardoEconomico" value="<?php echo $row['resguardoEconomico'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="velocidad">Velocidad</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="velocidad" id="velocidad" value="<?php echo $row['velocidad'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombreEquipo">nombreEquipo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombreEquipo" id="nombreEquipo" value="<?php echo $row['nombreEquipo'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sistemaOperativo">sistemaOperativo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sistemaOperativo" id="sistemaOperativo" value="<?php echo $row['sistemaOperativo'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="direccionIP">direccionIP</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccionIP" id="direccionIP" value="<?php echo $row['direccionIP'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="direccionMAC">direccionMAC</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccionMAC" id="direccionMAC" value="<?php echo $row['direccionMAC'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="procesador">procesador</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="procesador" id="procesador" value="<?php echo $row['procesador'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="noProcesadores">noProcesadores</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="noProcesadores" id="noProcesadores" value="<?php echo $row['noProcesadores'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="memoria">memoria</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="memoria" id="memoria" value="<?php echo $row['memoria'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="capAlmacenamiento">capAlmacenamiento</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="capAlmacenamiento" id="capAlmacenamiento" value="<?php echo $row['capAlmacenamiento'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="infraCritica">infraCritica</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="infraCritica" id="infraCritica" value="<?php echo $row['infraCritica'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="funcional">funcional</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="funcional" id="funcional" value="<?php echo $row['funcional'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="procesoNegocio">procesoNegocio</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="procesoNegocio" id="procesoNegocio" value="<?php echo $row['procesoNegocio'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tipo_uso">tipo_uso</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tipo_uso" id="tipo_uso" value="<?php echo $row['tipo_uso'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="actTecnologica">actTecnologica</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="actTecnologica" id="actTecnologica" value="<?php echo $row['actTecnologica'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="no_serie">no_serie</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="no_serie" id="no_serie" value="<?php echo $row['no_serie'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="tipo_equipo">tipo_equipo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tipo_equipo" id="tipo_equipo" value="<?php echo $row['tipo_equipo'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="marca">marca</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="marca" id="marca" value="<?php echo $row['marca'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="modelo">modelo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="modelo" id="modelo" value="<?php echo $row['modelo'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="antiguedad">antiguedad</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="antiguedad" id="antiguedad" value="<?php echo $row['antiguedad'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="entidad">entidad</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="entidad" id="entidad" value="<?php echo $row['entidad'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="municipio">municipio</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="municipio" id="municipio" value="<?php echo $row['municipio'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="domicilio">domicilio</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="domicilio" id="domicilio" value="<?php echo $row['domicilio'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="zipCode">zipCode</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipCode" id="zipCode" value="<?php echo $row['zipCode'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="reqMantto">reqMantto</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="reqMantto" id="reqMantto" value="<?php echo $row['reqMantto'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fallas">fallas</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fallas" id="fallas" value="<?php echo $row['fallas'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="descFalla">descFalla</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="descFalla" id="descFalla" value="<?php echo $row['descFalla'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="misionCritica">misionCritica</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="misionCritica" id="misionCritica" value="<?php echo $row['misionCritica'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comentarios">comentarios</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="comentarios" id="comentarios" value="<?php echo $row['comentarios'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="notas">notas</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="notas" id="notas" value="<?php echo $row['notas'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="migrar">migrar</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="migrar" id="migrar" value="<?php echo $row['migrar'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="no_activoFijo">no_activoFijo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="no_activoFijo" id="no_activoFijo" value="<?php echo $row['no_activoFijo'] ?>">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="bts" class="btn btn-success">Modificar Registro</button>
</form>
<?php
endif;
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes (al menos) un error en el UPDATE, eso hace que `$mysqli->prepare` falle, `$stmt` tendrá el valor FALSE y, como no es un objeto, no tendrá el método bind_param (que es el fallo que se muestra).

El error está aquí:

```
 ... zipCode=?, reqMantto, fallas=?, ...
```

la columna `reqMantto` debería tener un `=?` porque es un `UPDATE` y se le debe asignar un valor. Si después de corregir eso te sigue fallando, deberías verificar que el resto de nombres de las columnas están bien escritos, de lo contrario el UPDATE no será válido y obtendrás el mismo error.

Comment: Si, de hecho, es ese el error, detallitos que uno ni cuenta se da y son los que truenan los programas, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

`prepare()` te da un booleano si hay un error, así que deberías tener una condición que lo verifique en caso de ser `FALSE`, además debes determinar porque está entregando ese valor, si es un error en los nombres de las tabla/columnas o en la consulta.